# UTM tags for transactional emails

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, email, utm-parameters

I'd like to be able to track visitors from transactional emails in Google Analytics, but I'm not sure what values to use for the UTM tags.

**`utm_medium`** should obviously be "email", but what about **`utm_source`** and **`utm_campaign`**?

Is there any good practice for that? The only think I'd like is be consistent.

By "transactional emails" I mean emails like:

- You've got a new private message
- Confirm your email. etc.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to tag you "transactional" e-mails? By doing that you overrides the original source and medium that brought the user to your site.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the best practice but this one I have setup my UTM tags for my eCommerce site

For New Account creation

- Campaign Source : website
- Campaign Medium : email
- Campaign Name : new_account_email
- Campaign Content : hyperlink / calltoaction / confirm

For Shipment tracking email

- Campaign Source : website
- Campaign Medium : email
- Campaign Name : order_shipped
- Campaign Content : hyperlink / calltoaction / confirm

Please Note: *And the end of the day all fields naming does not matter because you'll be knowing for want campaign you are running those email, etc, etc.*

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are no standard practices for transactional emails but usually source would be the name of the tool or the software sending the email so depending on your case it could be:

`utm_source=mandrill` or `utm_source=sendgrid` for instance.